# Randomness in Python

Tags: python, random

I'm using `random.random()` to get a random float (obviously!).  But what I really want to do is something like:

```
there's a 30% chance my app does this:
  pass
else:
  pass
```

Can you guys help me structure this?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Between the vagueness of the question and the strange comment thread regarding the nature of randomness on @hd1's answer below, it's quite unclear.

Comment: @Dkamins, I edited the post to make it a little more clear, I hope. I need it to perform an action 30% of the time, otherwise, do something else.  Just looking for a general algorithm.   hd1's post seems to be it - I'm just trying to understand it a little bit more before I accept.

Comment: If you're thinking of "30%" as a float value, accept `hd1`'s answer; if you're thinking of it as "3 out of 10", accept Óscar López's answer. They're both correct, and equivalent, it's just a matter of which is more readable or seems more "right" in your case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if random.random() > 0.5: 
    # your app does this 
    pass
else: 
    # your app does that
    pass
```

Comment: It's probably easier to use `random() < x` since `x` would directly correspond to the probability of the condition's being true.

Comment: But does this answer the question? The asker wants to make it so that if he flips a coin repeatedly, it gives randomly ordered results, skewed 40% (or whatever) towards heads. Your answer could feasibly give 0% heads.

Comment: @Aerovistae OP has only suggested making the choice once, I think.

Comment: That doesn't actually change the math behind it. Once or a million times, this answer does not give a guaranteed X% chance.

Comment: The answer might be the same - but what I really meant was that random.random() was also determined.  So, for instance if .3 > .5 will always be false.  Could I use .3 > random.random() or will this skew my probabilities?

Comment: @Aerovistae, yes, that is what I'm trying to do!

Comment: @irrelephant Yes, but that could just keep returning something greater than 0.5, 100% of the time. It is not guaranteed to give an X% chance, like Tyler wants. Unless..and here my understanding of the random module falls short...the distribution of random.random() is completely uniform, so exactly half the results will be greater than 0.5 and half of them will be less? In that case, this answer is correct, and I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Aerovistae I guess that's a different question - I'm interpreting it as a random chance, and you're probably interpreting it as a random ordering.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Even a truly random sequence could just keep returning something greater than 0.5, 100% of the time. That's a perfectly reasonable result for something that has a 50% chance of happening. It's not the same thing as happening 50% of the times when run N times (except as N approaches infinity), but the OP asked for the former, not the latter. In other words, it's perfectly reasonable for something with a 50% chance of happening to happen, say, 9 times in 20 runs, or even 0 (it's just not that likely—the odds are 1/2^N).

Comment: I edited my question to make up for the fact that the randomness is determined already (at say, 30%).  Would .3 > random.random() solve this? or am I not understanding how the .5 works in the example?

Comment: @TylerSeymour: Yes, he's used .5 to mean a 50% chance; change it to .3 to mean a 30% chance. Most people would write this as `random.random() < .3`, but of course `.3 > random.random()` means the exact same thing, as would the answer's `random.random() > .7`.

Comment: @abarnert yes, I was under the impression the OP wanted exactly X% of the time, run N times, with randomly ordered results.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Well, that would require some kind of persistent information to be kept across runs, so let's hope the OP didn't want that.

Comment: @abarnert  Not necessarily. Take a list of length N, fill 40% of it with A at random positions, and the rest with B. Iterate through the list to get your sequential results.

Comment: @Aerovistae: How is that list (or, rather, `iter(thatlist)`) not "persistent information to be kept across runs"? (And you're assuming that "across runs" means "within one process execution"—think about what happens if you want that "40% of the time" to apply to all runs of the script by anyone, anywhere in the world!)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
if random.randint(1, 10) in (1, 2, 3):
    print '30% chance'
else:
    print '70% chance'
```

Here `randint` will generate a number between 1-10, there's a 30% chance that it's between 1-3 and a 70% chance that it's between 4-10

Comment: Less flexible than @hd1's method, since this can only do equal probabilities, but convenient. Note that you could also skip the `== 1` if you wanted.

Comment: This is a better solution when your probabilities are best described as "1 in 2" or "1 in 3". Of course for a rational number, you have a choice of describing it either way, so `if random.randrange(10) < 3` is just as reasonable as `random.random() < .3`; it's just a matter of which one seems clearer to you.